# Why is the clock frozen?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

When I'm in the space center, the little box with the time in it just reads `Year-232, Day-161--3h,-14m`. Why is this? Is there some sort of maxint that the developers implemented?

Comment: A screenshot would be really helpful in this case.  I forget if it's F1 or F2 as the default key for screenshots.

Comment: @MBraedley I'm not sure if a screenshot is needed, I just put in what the clock read because it's only text. A screenshot seems like overkill.

Comment: I want to see what you're seeing, that's all.  A picture tells a thousand words, after all.

Comment: Okay, I'll see if I can get it, the save file is corrupted for some reason now, so I'm not sure how much it really matters to me, but i'll try.

Comment: @MBraedley, It seems as though due to the save file corruption, I can no longer take a screenshot. And now I have an entirely new problem...

Comment: Is there a reason you can't user the 'print screen' option on your PC. to get a screen shot?

Comment: @JamesJenkins I think he means that he can't open the file anymore.

Comment: That's very close to 2147483647 seconds, which is the maximum number that can fit in a signed 32-bit integer.  You probably overflowed the internal clock.

Answer (score 1):

If the time is negative, then something happened that shouldn't have, this is also probably why your save is corrupt, you will have to restart or try modifying the save.